# status_format for email sender in neomutt

Tags: notifications, mutt, notify-send, neomutt

I am using Neomutt, and I want to display notifications whenever new mail comes in the inbox. I used the `new_mail_command` to send a notification via `notify-send`. But I also want to include the sender's address in the notification. Is there any way to do that? Maybe some status_format type of thing?

Comment: what is your mailbox backend? is it IMAP, maildir, mbox?

Comment: It is IMAP.

Really thanks!

Comment: If it was maildir or notmuch it would be easy. With IMAP I don't think this is possible using mutt/neomutt since new_mail_command uses status_format expandos therefore there's no option to get the senders. But it should be possible to use some biff like program that does that and completely move this functionality elsewhere.

Comment: Really thanks for your response! I will look up for biff. Also is there any way to scrape out the headers from incoming emails? Maybe I can just parse that header for relevant information.